# Name of declared class in php

Tags: php, class, object

I have searched Google and stack overflow forums for hours and found nothing but the get_declared_classes function which only returns the class name oppsed to the declared object name.

Here what I am trying to do : I need to get all the names of the declared object within a page so it can return the scope basically, Because i am working on a large mvc frame work project where some class instance's have dynamic names.

For example

```
$a = new foo();
$b = new foo();
$c = new foo();

$x = new bar();
$y = new bar();
$z = new bar();
```

I need a function that returns the a,b,c x,y,z based upon the class name input

e.g

```
function blah(foo / bar){
return name of for / bar 
}
```

I don't even know if this is possible but would be really helpful determining how the class's have been declared.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you mean. Would `var_dump($this);` do what you need?

Comment: You should read about reflection in PHP http://il1.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php

Comment: var_dump returns information on a specific variable, i need a list of class instance's that i don't know the name off.

Comment: So in your example you want `blah('foo')` return an array `['a','b','c']` (with or without the $) and `blah('bar')` should return `['x', 'y', 'z']` - is that right?

Comment: if @vstm's question is correct, then it raises the new question of "why do you need this", because it's an incredibly bad design principle if you do... and meaningless (I can change the variable names I use at whim, or have multiple variables all referencing the same object instance) consider using `collections` rather than individually named variables

Comment: exactly what i want vstm :D

Answer (score 2):

I hope that I understood you correctly.

1. Get all defined variables: [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/get_defined_vars)
2. Filter objects by their type: [is_object()](http://php.net/is_object)

[→ Ideone.com live version](http://ideone.com/xYKBa2)

```
class Bar {
}
$blub = new Bar();

$vars = get_defined_vars();
$vars = array_filter($vars, function($var) {
    return is_object($var) && $var instanceof Bar;
});

foreach ($vars as $object) {
    echo 'There is one "Bar"!';
}
```

You can also use [get_class()](http://php.net/get_class) for dynamically checking the class name.
[→ Ideone.com live version](http://ideone.com/spmJib)

```
class Bar {}
class Foo {}

// we do not want them to be listed in the output
class EvilBar {}
class EvilFoo {}

$a = new Bar();
$b = new Foo();
$c = new EvilBar();
$d = new EvilFoo();

$vars = get_defined_vars();
$vars = array_filter($vars, function($var) {
    return is_object($var) && strpos(get_class($var), 'Evil') !== 0;
});

foreach ($vars as $object) {
    // Doesn't begin with "Evil"
    if (strpos(get_class($object), 'Evil') !== 0) {
        echo 'There is one non-evil object and its class name is: ', get_class($object), "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: After I posted my answer - I worked out this is what I thought he ment - I think you're right with this one. +1

Comment: Although perhaps to list all instantiated objects, rather than all objects of a specific type, just
foreach ($vars as $object) echo get_class($object);

Comment: Note that rules of variable scoping still apply